# Convert string array to lowercase

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have string array `string[] MyArray`. What is the quickest (meaning least code, not fastest performance) way to convert all string array elements to lowercase?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
var MyArrayLower = MyArray.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant()).ToArray();
```

(or

```
MyArray = MyArray.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant()).ToArray();
```

if you want to replace the existing array with a new instance of `string[]`.)

Comment: If you want to honor regional settings you should probably use `ToLower()` instead of `ToLowerInvariant()`.

Answer (score 24):

Easiest approach:

```
MyArray = Array.ConvertAll(MyArray, d => d.ToLower());
```

Comment: `MyArray = MyArray.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());` does not work for me.  This should be `MyArray = Array.ConvertAll(MyArray, d => d.ToLower());`.

Answer (score 10):

Without creating a new Array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
    MyArray[i] = MyArray[i].ToLower();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myArray = Array.ConvertAll(myArray, x => x.ToLower());
```

Note: This is very close to 'prasadd' answer but works with string arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
strin[] MyArrayLower = (from str in MyArray
                        select str.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
var lowercaseStringArray = myStringArray.Select(c => c.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -6):

I wouldn't use this in production:

```
MyArray = string.Join(";", MyArray).ToLower().Split(';');
```